# Better way to query database with array

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, express

Below is my current code, however, I'm pretty sure that it sucks. It works and does the job but I think I might fall victim to SQL injection with my current solution. I'm very new to both Javascript and SQL so please forgive my stupid question.

```
app.post('/api/v1/relevantEvents', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        let events = req.body.cookie;
        if (!events) events = [];
        let a = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            a += "subject = '" + events[i] + "'";
            if (i !== events.length - 1) a += " OR ";
        }
        const allEvents = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE subject IS NULL or " + a);
        res.json(allEvents.rows);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```

The body of the request is an array with values that exist in some row.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, your SQL query is at risk of an SQL injection. Therefore, I would recommend a change to the constant `allEvents` assuming `a` is a string/text:

```js
const allEvents = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE subject IS NULL or $1::text", [a]);
});
```